# Writing columns to a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I would like to update a column called `Score` for a specific row in a csv file. When a button is pressed, I would like the code to search the csv file until the row with the specified name is found (which is stored in variable `name` and randomly pulled from the csv file in a previous function called `NameGenerator()`), and update the relevant cell in the `Score` column to increment by 1.

Please note I am using an excel file saved as a .csv for this.

Any ideas how to do this? The code below does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def Correct():
    writer = csv.writer(namelist_file)
    score=0
    for row in writer:
        if row[0] == name:
            score=score+1
            writer.writerow([col[1]] = score)
```

[![The CSV file looks as follows
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP47y.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP47y.png)
So for example if the name tom is selected (elsewhere in the code, however stored in variable `name`), his score of 3 should be incremented by 1, turning into 4.

Here is what the function which pulls a random name from the csv file looks like:

```
def NameGenerator():
    namelist_file = open('StudentNames&Questions.csv')
    reader = csv.reader(namelist_file)
    rownum=0
    global array
    array=[]
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] != '':
            array.append(row[0])
            rownum=rownum+1
    length = len(array)-1
    i = random.randint(1,length)
    name = array[i]
    return name
```

Comment: Does the first line of your file contains the headers ? Can you provide a sample input ?

Comment: Yes the first line does contain headers. There are no inputs currently.

Comment: It is currently a column full of 0's

Comment: Can you write a sample of your input csv + another with what you expect it to be after running your function ?

Comment: Little confused with what you mean, however have made edits. Hopefully this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if this works :

```
import sys
import random,csv

def update(cells):
    d=""
    for cell in cells:
        d=d + str(cell)+","
    return d[:-1]

def update_score(name):
    with open('StudentNames&Questions.csv', 'r') as file:
        data = file.readlines()
    name_index = - 1
    score_index = -1
    headers = data[0]
    for index,header in enumerate(headers.split(",")):
        if header.strip() == 'Names':
            name_index=index
        if header.strip() == 'Score':
            score_index=index
    if name_index == -1 or score_index == -1:
        print "Headers not found"
        sys.exit()

    for index,row in enumerate(data):
        cells = row.split(",")
        if cells[name_index] == name:
            cells[score_index] = int(cells[score_index]) + 1
        data[index]=update(cells)

    with open('/Users/kgautam/tmp/tempfile-47', 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(data)


def NameGenerator():
    namelist_file = open('StudentNames&Questions.csv')
    reader = csv.reader(namelist_file)
    rownum=0
    global array
    array=[]
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] != '':
            array.append(row[0])
            rownum=rownum+1
    length = len(array)-1
    i = random.randint(1,length)
    name = array[i]
    return name


randome_name=NameGenerator()
update_score(randome_name)
```

Comment: Thank you i shall give this a go. Is this the most efficient way though? It seems like a lot of code for a reasonably simple task

Comment: I think maybe you misunderstood my request. The program already generates the name. It then searches the csv file untill it finds that name, and then increments that players score by writing to the csv file and updating the cell next to their name.

Comment: @CallumTwig, this program is not generating a name, but works on an existing one. The sample name used in the program is "abc". I have updated my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: The program does generate a name. Theres a function which randomly pulls a name from a list (on a csv file)

Comment: I also think it is important to mention that the score shouldnt incrememnt automatically. When a button is clicked i want a function to run which then increments the score.

Comment: Yes unfortunately the updated answer doesn't fully answer my request. Would you like me to re-explain exactly what i am after?

Comment: Please re-read my post. Its been updated and hopefully more clear

Comment: Updated the answer.